# Django: migrations for tables that are not linked to models

Tags: django, database, django-south

I have a set of tables (mostly some denormilized pre-calculated values storages) that are not linked to any model, I just use raw select queries on them. Is it possible to use any migration frameworks for them (for example, I want to add column and deploy this change to all environments).
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the usual migrations system.

First, [create an empty migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) (in whatever app is most appropriate).

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty yourappname
```

Then put in whatever [`RunSQL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) operations you need (including the SQL for reverting the changes, if you want).

```
operations = [
    migrations.RunSQL("CREATE ...",
                      "DROP ..."),
    ...
]
```

The result can be run right alongside your migrations for Django models.

```
python manage.py migrate
```